# Changing the memory address of a variable

Tags: c++

Can you change the memory address of a variable?
Like where the variable sits in memory.

If so how could you go around doing that?

I am using the Compiler in Visual Studio 2019, if that helps.

Comment: Is there a reason to change the memory location? You can use a pointer to that location instead though.

Comment: If you define a variable just before the one you are talking about, the address will change because the new one has taken the address.

Comment: I feel your question is subject to a certain amount of interpretation. Can you elaborate what you mean with an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Declare another variable and assign the original value to it...

Comment: You wouldn't.   A variable has only one address throughout its lifetime.   The only way to obtain a variable with a different address is to obtain a different variable.

Answer (score 3):

> Can you change the memory address of a variable? Like where the variable sits in memory.

No. You cannot change the memory address of a variable.

All objects stay in the memory address where they were created. And the programmer cannot choose that adderss for any variable (within the language); the language implementation will do that for you.

Outside the scope of C++ language, in case you are interested in choosing that address (rather than changing the address at runtime wihch is not possible), there may be language implementation specific ways available (I don't know if there are for MSVC).

Comment: what does stop us from first creating a pointer to a specific location and using that? that specific location can technically be considered a variable. am I wrong in this?

Comment: What about paging? Page paged out from one location, paged in to different location.

Comment: @Marichyasana The C++ language has no knowledge of paging. Within standard means at least, C++ programs can only interact with the virtual memory.

Comment: @Rika No, pointing to a memory location doesn't make that memory location a variable in C++.

Comment: I mean, you can store/read from it, and pointer is just a place holder for the actual place where the values are stored/read from! would it not make it a variable?

Comment: @Rika No, being able to store/read from some a memory location does not make that memory location a variable. Variables are created by declarations.

Comment: You are right though my point was something else. what I was trying to convey is that variables are highlevel concepts that allow you to read/write to a memory location without you being concerned with lowlevel intricacies.

Comment: @Rika: A variable is an object with a name. You can also create objects at a specified location using _placement new_, which does almost what you want. But that object won't have a name. Besides names, variables also have scope.

Comment: @MSalters Technically, there can be variables with no name.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can always create a new variable, copy the contents, and delete the original. But if you need all existing references to still access the original information you would need to use a pointer, and update the pointer to the new location.

Comment: Rarely do you see two opposing answers were both are equally correct. (reminds you of a multiple choice test...)

Comment: `you can always create a new variable` Once you create a "*new*" variable it's no longer *the same* variable. What you propose does not change the address of an existing variable, it just copies its value to a new location.

Comment: @dxiv yes, you're right, l was just offering a workaround for something that, as you pointed out, is not possible.. unfortunately we don't know why they want to do it so we can't dig any deeper

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can always create a new variable, copying the contents and erasing the original. But when you need all the available references to keep accessing the original information, you would have to use a pointer and update the pointer to the new location.